# Spark2 reads ORC files much slower than Spark1

Tags: apache-spark

I found that Spark2 loads ORC files much slower than Spark1, and then I tried some methods to speed up Spark2, but no success. Codes show as below:

*Spark 1.5*

```
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("LoadOrc")
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .set("spark.akka.frameSize", "512")
      .set("spark.akka.timeout","800s")
      .set("spark.storage.blockManagerHeartBeatMs", "300000")
      .set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max","1024m")
      .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
    val start = System.nanoTime()
    val ret = hiveContext.read.orc(args(0)).count()
    val end = System.nanoTime()
    println(s"count: $ret")
    println(s"Time taken: ${(end - start) / 1000 / 1000} ms")
    sc.stop()
```

*Spark UI*

[Spark1 UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQQYM.png)

*results*

```
count: 2290811187
Time taken: 401063 ms
```

*Spark 2*

```
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("LoadOrc")
      .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .config("spark.akka.frameSize", "512")
      .config("spark.akka.timeout","800s")
      .config("spark.storage.blockManagerHeartBeatMs", "300000")
      .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max","1024m")
      .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    println(spark.time(spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc")
      .load(args(0)).count()))

    spark.close()
```

*Spark UI*

[Spark2 UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlC3n.png)

*results*

```
Time taken: 1384464 ms
2290811187
```

Comment: The same Spark submit: --master yarn-cluster --conf spark.default.parallelism=800 --num-executors 80 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 2g

Comment: the bug has been fixed in spark2.4